# Unity Build is showing GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib' is Missing.?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, game-development

I was trying to build my unity project but it is showing this-[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWGLD.png)
GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib' is missing AndroidManifest.xml file. UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was changing file name 'GooglePlayGamesManifest.androidlib' to 'GooglePlayGamesManifest' in Assets/Plugins/Android folder. Or do opposite way.